# how to Convert String to Date in flex?

Tags: apache-flex, date

Actually in my Flex Application DataGrid column getting one value like `Sat Sep 1 00:00:00 GMT+0530 2012`
how to convert this String as Date like `2012/09/01`

i'm doing converting String Date but it giving `null` value...hear is my sample code

```
var startDS:String = saveDataGrid.selectedItem.startDate;
var sDate:Date=DateField.stringToDate(startDs,"YYYY/MM/DD");
Alert.show(sDate+"--===--"+startDS);//Alert giving  null--===--Sat Sep 1 00:00:00 GMT+0530 2012
```

please help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var startDS:String = "10022008";

var sDate:Date=DateField.stringToDate(startDS,"MMDDYYYY");

Alert.show(sDate+"--===--"+startDS);
```

You might also need to have a glance at http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=formatters_4.html

output will be, "Thu Oct 2 00:00:00 GMT+0530 2008--===--10022008"

Comment: but it is giving null value...var s:Date = DateField.stringToDate(startDS,"EEE MMM D HH:NN:SS TZD YYYY"); based on above example..